# Find the min distance between two distinct elements of an array

Tags: c, algorithm

I have tried to solve the following problem using sort the array and return the difference between second element of an array and first element of an array.
But it didn't pass the whole test cases, and the correctness was 42%

Is that approach wrong ?

[image]

Comment: Compare all pairs in the sortef array and minimize.

Comment: Try your approach using pen and paper on the [7, 2, 4, 8] array and see what happens.

Comment: Please don't post (unreadably small) images of text — copy the text into the question.

Comment: Sort the array can be part of the solution, but the minimum difference won't always be between the first and second elements in sorted order.  Sorting reduces the problem time complexity from O(N²) to O(N.logN) — which doesn't matter in the slightest for arrays under some small size, such as a hundred elements, but does matter a lot on large arrays, such as ones with a million entries.  Measurement would tell where the breakeven point is.  If you ever found identical numbers, you could stop your search early — the difference doesn't get smaller than zero.

Comment: Glad I'm not a copyright attorney for Codility Limited....

Answer (score 0):

Your approach will miss out few cases such as:

1. If array consists of [2, 3, 0, 2] -> post sorting you will have [0, 2, 2, 3].
   Now with your approach you will return '2' whereas the answer is '0'.
2. Also with your approach you may miss out the time complexity constraint.

To solve this you could use a modified merge sort which will have a worst case complexity of O(nlog(n)).

Try out the below code, although it is written in Javascript, you could figure out the logic behind..I hope this would sort your issue.

```js
let dist = -1;
function checkDist(a,b) {
    let cnt = Math.abs(a - b);
    if(cnt < dist || -1 === dist)
        dist = cnt;
}

function mergeSort(a, l, r){
    if(l<r){
        let m = l + parseInt((r-l)/2);
        a = mergeSort(a, l, m);
        a = mergeSort(a, m+1, r);
        a = merge(a, l, m, r);
    }
    return a;
}

function merge(a, l, m, r){
    let pa = l, pb = m+1, i = 0;
    let temp = [];

    while(pa < m+1 && pb < r+1){
        if(a[pa] <= a[pb]){
            checkDist(a[pa], a[pb]);
            temp[i] = a[pa];
            pa++;
        } else {
            checkDist(a[pa], a[pb]);
            temp[i] = a[pb];
            pb++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    while(pa < m+1){
        checkDist(a[pa], a[m+1]);
        temp[i] = a[pa];
        i++;
        pa++;
    }
    while(pb < r+1){
        checkDist(a[r+1], a[pb]);
        temp[i] = a[pb];
        i++;
        pb++;
    }

    let k = l;
    for(let e of temp){
        a[k] = e;
        k++;
    }

    return a;
}

function main() {
    let a = [3,20,1,17]; //--->INPUT ARRAY
    let r = a.length - 1;
    mergeSort(a, 0, r);
    console.log('Min Distance->', dist);
    console.log('Sorted Array->', a);
}

main();
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Answer] pages sometime.  Be cautious about answering questions in C with code in Javascript.  It is not always a good choice — it is better to use C.  You could avoid the `dist = -1` initialization by setting it to the absolute difference between any two members of the array before you ever call `checkDist()`.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan for the tips. Will certainly read  'About and How to Answer pages' and will take care of the language used in the Question.